# How to set Wifi wep key, only programmlly?

Tags: android

I have a 40-bit hexadecimal WEP key in the setting of my router.
I tried to set the "40-bit hex wep key" in

"Wireless & Network"-"Wifi settings"-"Modify network"-"password"

but...it seems not work.
Although in "Wi-Fi network", it shows this network is "connected"
Ping returns "Request timeout"

WHERE to set it? or it can only be set in program?

Comment: It helps if you actually describe the problem. What happens when you try? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @David Schwartz After set it, I Ping my android tablet, and "request timeout" is shown. by the way I am using motorola xoom android 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I **wifi-settings**, if you turned on your wifi, all available wifi access points will be displayed. You have to click any one of them and input the password/WEP key.

If you didn't find any access point, you have to click Add-Wifi network and then it will ask for network SSID, security type, etc.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thanks! I can find my access point. Input the hex wepkey in "Password", press "Save", and this network turn to "connected". But Ping is not worked.